# How to print values of JLabel and JTable in JPanel

Tags: java, printing, jtable, jlabel, jtextfield

So I want to print the values of my JLabel, JTextField, and JTable within the JPanel and **not the JPanel itself**.

What I always search always result in printing the whole Panel which includes buttons that is unnecessary: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufwga.png)

I did find something quite useful that prints just the JTable.
it outputs the following image: [image]

Here is my current code which just outputs the JTable:

```java
try {
    jTable3.print(JTable.PrintMode.NORMAL);
}
catch (java.awt.print.PrinterException e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

**My question is how can I print the values of my JLabel, JTextField and JTable within the JPanel? I'm also open to other suggestions.**

**Thank you very much**

Comment: To clarify: you're trying to print something like [this](https://cdn.vertex42.com/ExcelTemplates/Images/purchase-order-template.png) (maybe without the shipping information)?

Comment: Also, the code you used to generate the first image would also be appreciated.